# Sharepoint Search access denied?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

I have a bunch of new users added to Visitors, Members and Owners groups. 
However when they try and search for anythng they are shown Access Denied.
Are there permission settings in Enterprise Search Center that I need to configure?

Comment: Are they shown Access Denied when accessing search, on the results page or when clicking on the results themselves?

Comment: @Dave Wise I think I overlooked it. I have the search fields in all my site collectiosn point to the enterprise search center and I forgot to grant user permissions to the enterprise search center site collection . It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the users have permission to view the search center site collection